# SSIS variables not containing correct values when running as job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, etl

In ssis(2005) I am using an execute SQL task to call a stored procedure. The stored procedure takes 3 params, all 3 are ssis variables. My package executes without problem in dev but fails when running as a job.

The log gives the following msg: Executing the query "Exec nx_sp_WriteFLHeader ?,?,?" failed with the following error: "Unspecified error". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Using Sql server profiler I can see the stored procedure is called with incorrect values, (1,null,null) in dev it would be somthing like 454,404,"sometext".

When running as a job I can see the ssis variables successfully being used in in other tasks, it is if the variables are out of scope by the time I am trying to use them. I did declare the variables at the highest level.

Thanks

Solved: In the execute SQL task, Parameter Mapping section, one of the parameter's Data Type's was defined as Numeric. After changing it to Long my job executes successfully. The ssis variable I am passing was declared as an int32.

Comment: What are the variables that you are using?, are they system variables?, or user variables?

Comment: are the parameter types of the SP the same in dev and prod?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: In the execute SQL task, Parameter Mapping section, one of the parameter's Data Type's was defined as Numeric. After changing it to Long my job executes successfully. The ssis variable I am passing was declared as an int32.